# ColorConstants in VB6 to VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I am converting a VB6 ActiveX Dll to VB.net.  In order to support legacy systems, I need the COM interface to act the same way it did prior to the update.

I have two instances where a VB6 ColorConstant is passed back and forth as a property in VB6.

**VB6**

```
Public Property Let ProgressBarColor(color As ColorConstants)
  userform.ProgressBarColor = color
End Property

Public Property Get ProgressBarColor() As ColorConstants
  ProgressBarColor = userform.ProgressBarColor
End Property
```

Here is what I have in .Net

**VB.NET**

```
Public Property ProgressBarColor() As Long
  Get
    userform.ProgressBarColor
  End Get
  Set(ByVal Value As Long)
     ProgressBarColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(Value)
  End Set
End Property
```

Is there a way to have the VB.Net handle this as a Color Constant?

Comment: Have you tried substituting the Color Constants with `System.Drawing.Color` Constants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In VB6 colors are represented as Longs, and in VB.NET colors are represented as Structures.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ys84h69%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> In Visual Basic 6.0, colors were represented by a value of type Long;
>   in Visual Basic 2008 colors are of type Color. In Visual Basic 6.0,
>   constants were provided for eight standard colors; in Visual Basic
>   2008 there are more than 100 named colors.
>
> ***Tip***
>
> To find an equivalent value for a Visual Basic 6.0 color that is
>   not a standard color, you can use the ColorTranslator class and pass
>   it the Long value of the Visual Basic 6.0 color.
>
> **Color Constants**
>
> In Visual Basic 6.0, constants were provided for system colors that
>   could be used to map a color to the user's system preferences. In
>   Visual Basic 2008, the system colors are of type SystemColors.

To keep backward functionally you'll have to keep on passing color as Longs, change your code to use the `ColorTranslator` class like so:

```
Public Property ProgressBarColor() As Int32
  Get
    Return System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(userform.ProgressBarColor)
  End Get
  Set(ByVal value As Int32)
     userform.ProgressBarColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(value)
  End Set
End Property
```

Comment: In VB.Net a long is 64-bits, but in VB6 a Long is 32-bits. Are you sure this shouldn't be using `Integer` or `Int32` instead of `Long`?